# How to obtain Linux syscall name from the syscall number?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I need to translate Linux syscall number into human-readable name. With kernel 2.6.32, I was extracting the names from _*NR** macros in */usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h*, which was hacky but it worked. Now I need to make it work on kernel 3.2.0 and this file is no longer there.

What is the least hacky and most portable way of mapping the Linux syscall number into human-readable name? E.g. 1->exit, 6->close etc.

Comment: There is no programatic way to do it that i know. Only digginig in kernel sources. [This file contains the system call numbers](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h)

Answer (score 4):

The file `<sys/syscall.h>` defines a lot of `SYS_` macros (indirectly through `bits/syscall.h` on my system). For example:

```
#define SYS_eventfd __NR_eventfd
#define SYS_eventfd2 __NR_eventfd2
#define SYS_execve __NR_execve
#define SYS_exit __NR_exit
#define SYS_exit_group __NR_exit_group
#define SYS_faccessat __NR_faccessat
```

Is this what you are looking? I am not sure if this is part of your question, but then you can do:

```
switch(code) {
#define syscode_case(x) case x: return #x;
    syscode_case(SYS_eventfd);
    syscode_case(SYS_eventf2);
}
```

You still need to know what are the available macros, but you do not need to know the actual value.

Edit:

My source is the [`man 2 syscall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html), which states:

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>`   /* For SYS_xxx definitions
```

Comment: @GrzegorzJakacki Is this not what you are looking for? The macro names are portable.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware that I can do the following to get list of SYS_... macros:
`echo "#include<sys/syscall.h>" | gcc -dN -E - | awk '($1=="#define" && $2~/^SYS_/){print $2}'`
so I can find out the list of SYS_... macros. The question is whether going by SYS_... macros is the best way of mapping the syscall numbers into names. It is unclear to me what is the difference between SYS_... and __NR_... macros? Is it possible that some system calls won't be covered by SYS_... macros? Is the number present in EAX register just before the syscall kernel trap the same value as defined by SYS_...?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do a `grep -rA3 'SYSCALL_DEFINE.\?(<syscallname>,' *` in your kernel sources directory (substitute `<syscallname>` with your actual syscall).
2. You can `man syscalls` and start looking from there on.
3. Check [here](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) and be patient (link reported broken in the comments)
4. [This one seems to be working](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/)

Comment: That link is now rotten, please check if there's an alternative.